# java code to create a unique code for a combination

Tags: java, c, math, logic

I have a table which have field "offerId" and suppose in my list I have three offer for each user (and each user might have already one, two or no offer) than I will have eight category (2^3 = 8 combinations) and I want to create a unique Id for each category by using offerId for further process. 
So can any one please help me to make logic for the same in java or c.

The code should be like :

```
categoryId getCategory(offerId[])
{
  /* all computations */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit set showing all combinations will work.

This is a bad design, in my opinion.  Cleverness like this is neither extensible nor welcome.

If there's a one to many relationship between user and offer, I think it's clearer to give a user a collection of offers rather than bit twiddling.